# Getting a JavaFX event listener to talk to my method

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I have a calculator with several fields and a slider. The **tip**, **total** and **amount per person** should be calculated based on the **Amount**, **slider**(tip percentage) and **# of People.**

This may be messy, I'm a student. I was able to bind the tip to the slider as the tip and the slider should be the same values. Amount and number of People should be changing values so I did not bind them, but added listeners using the lambda below.

Unfortunately, the lambda didn't work and I suspected I needed to use changelistener as opposed to just listener and pass in the new values. However, when I created seperate changelisteners and commented out the original listeners, total and amount failed to change at all. The only way I can keep it partially working is with duplicate listeners. However, when I change the amount from 100 to 200 amount per person updates and tip and total do not update. Errors indicate an issue with one directional binding but no clues how to fix it. What am I doing wrong?

```
package application;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Labeled;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class TipCalculatorController2 {

private static final NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
private static final NumberFormat percent = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();

private BigDecimal tipPercentage = new BigDecimal(0.15);


@FXML
private Label amountLabel;

@FXML
private Label tipPercentageLabel;

@FXML
private TextField amountTextField;

@FXML
private TextField tipTextField;

@FXML
private Slider tipPercentageSlider;

@FXML
private TextField totalTextField;

@FXML
private TextField perPersonTextField;

@FXML
private TextField numPeopleTextField;

BigDecimal amount;
BigDecimal numPeople;
BigDecimal total;
BigDecimal tip;
BigDecimal splitTip;
//BigDecimal tipPercentage nope this breaks everything;
protected long number;

@FXML 
private void calculate() {

    try {
        amount = new BigDecimal(amountTextField.getText());     
        numPeople = new BigDecimal(numPeopleTextField.getText());
        }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        return;
        }
    tip = amount.multiply(tipPercentage);
    total = amount.add(tip);
    BigDecimal tipPercentage = BigDecimal.valueOf(tipPercentageSlider.getValue());
    splitTip = tip.divide(numPeople);
    perPersonTextField.setText(currency.format(splitTip));
    tipTextField.setText(currency.format(tip));
    totalTextField.setText(currency.format(total));

}

 @FXML
 public void initialize() {
    currency.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    tipTextField.textProperty().bind(tipPercentageSlider.valueProperty().asString("%.0f"));
    amountTextField.textProperty().addListener(e -> calculate());
    tipTextField.textProperty().addListener(e -> calculate());
    totalTextField.textProperty().addListener(e -> calculate());

    amountTextField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>(){
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            number = Long.parseLong(newValue);
            amount = BigDecimal.valueOf(number);
            //amountTextField.setText(currency.format(amount));
            calculate();
        }
    });

    tipTextField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            number = Long.parseLong(newValue);
            tip = BigDecimal.valueOf(number);
            //tipTextField.setText(currency.format(tip));
        }
    });

    totalTextField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            number = Long.parseLong(newValue);
            total = BigDecimal.valueOf(number);
            //totalTextField.setText(currency.format(total));
        }
    });

    tipPercentageSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
            tipPercentage = BigDecimal.valueOf(newValue.intValue() / 100.0);
            tipPercentageLabel.setText(percent.format(tipPercentage));
            totalTextField.setText(currency.format(total));
            perPersonTextField.setText(currency.format(splitTip));
        }
   });

 }
```

}

Repeating error in the stacktrace: Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: A bound value cannot be set.
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl$TextProperty.set(TextInputControl.java:1321)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.setText(TextInputControl.java:349)
    at application.TipCalculatorController2.calculate(TipCalculatorController2.java:65)
    at application.TipCalculatorController2.access$0(TipCalculatorController2.java:57)
    at application.TipCalculatorController2$4.changed(TipCalculatorController2.java:116)

Comment: What are the FXML properties of numPeopleTextField? Does it have a max bound value? Is that value set lower than 200?

Comment: Don't see anything limiting the value in the textfield, unfortunately